# C#: get web camera name for FFmpeg

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-capture

In my C# app I'm using FFmpeg to stream desktop and it works fine. I also want FFmpeg to publish video from web camera. The problem is, that when I use desktop as input, device name parameter is already known (-i video=UScreenCapture), but it's not  when I want to use web camera and microphone. So, my question is, how to get web camera and microphone names using C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to answer my own questions, but this time I'll do that.
There is "list_devices" command in FFmpeg (ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy). It gives you list of audio and video inputs. As you can guess, I solved the problem, redirecting FFmpeg's output into my app, executing this command and picking camera/microphone names from it.

Comment: But these name cannot work in c# code i am giving audio device name in C# as it is i am giving in CMD but it not working in C# CODE